# Can I receive generic type or list of this type

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, inheritance

I have class BaseEntity like below.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : Notifiable
{
}
```

I want create a class receiving a generic type and this type can be BaseEntity or IEnumerable of BaseEntity is this possible?

```
public abstract class BaseDTO<T> where T : BaseEntity OR IEnumerable<BaseEntity>
{}
```

Comment: Why use generics here? Just use `IEnumerable<BaseEntity>` and if it is a single element, your enumerable is a single element. It wouldn't make sense for it to be either the base class or an enumerable of the base class.

Comment: You can't do this. But @RonBeyer is right, why would you **want** to do this? This seems like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I thinking that using Base or enumerable has more simple applicability for inheritance classes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is the best answer, but I do this.

I create a Interface IBaseDTO and implemented two classes (BaseDTO and BaseListDTO)

```
public interface IBaseDTO
{
}

public abstract class BaseDTO<T> : IBaseDTO
        where T : BaseEntity
{
}

public abstract class BaseListDTO<T> : IBaseDTO
    where T : IEnumerable<BaseEntity>
{
}
```